# how to grab/display curl response after post form

Tags: curl

How could I get the response of server when I filled form and posted it? 
I know it process because when I posted wrong data, I got response. When I do correct, got nothing.

I used this:

```
curl -X POST -F 'email=root@root.com' -F 'password=root' http://webpage.com/ > response.txt
```

but what I see I dont have any result inside response.txt

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the header files for example using argument -v

```
curl -X POST -d 'email=root@root.com' 
-d 'password=root' 'http://webpage.com/' -v
```